any way to deduplicate #![feature(...)] annotations across workspace?
I have a workspace with many crates. I end up having to add the same #![feature(...)] flags to each crate. Is there any way to write them down in just one place, possibly by having cargo pass them as CLI flags to rustc?
(note: this is pretty hard to search for because feature is such a heavily overloaded term in the context of rust compilation).

Using include! would be about the only thing I think. Cargo can't do it itself so a workspace doesn't help and I haven't seen an option for it via RUSTFLAGS.

@kmdreko Even with include!() that doesn't work... which surprised me.

If those crates have only non-library targets, you could use required-features in their Cargo.toml, to disable this targets when given feature is not present.

@AleksanderKrauze This is about Cargo features, not Rust features.

Ah, you are right. I feel silly now.
